# Leaflet Choropleth Map and D3 Line Graph Interference

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I am trying to create a choropleth map in Leaflet with a D3 line graph. I followed [this tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) to create a choropleth map and I followed [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/benjchristensen/2579599) to create a D3 line graph. When I tried to put the two of them together, the Leaflet choropleth map takes on the style that was meant for the D3 line graph, specifically this CSS style:

```
path {
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1;
        fill: none;
    }
```

The states outlines are steelblue instead of white, which was define by this function:

```
        function style(feature) {
           return {
               weight: 2,
               opacity: 1,
               color: 'white',
               dashArray: '3',
               fillOpacity: 0.7,
               fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density)
               };
          }
```

The states also have no fill because of the CSS style above.

Does anyone has an idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: how about an online demo?

Comment: @JonatasWalker I was trying to put my code on jsfiddle but I can't seem to use more than one framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your code create two separate svg elements?
Then you can use CSS to stlye them separately, e.g:

if the svg for the map was created inside a div with id="map",
you could address the paths for that like so:

```
#map path {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
```

if the svg for the graph was created inside a div with id="graph"
you could address the paths for that like so:

```
#graph path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1;
    fill: none;
}
```